# forkJoin never finishes even though complete() is called

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to run a `forkJoin`, but it isn't running the `pipe()`. It runs the two methods in the array, but not the result, and I am not sure why...

in the `onStart()` is where I am calling `forkJoin()` but `here` never prints to the console. Am I missing a `sub.complete()` somewhere?

```js
export MyClass extends ParentClass {
      override onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        forkJoin([this.#addPhysics3D(), this.#addPhysics2D()]).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            console.log('here');
          })
        ).subscribe();
      }

      #addPhysics3D() {
        return new Observable<void>(sub => {
          try {
            import('@engine/physics').then(physics => {
              if (!physics) return sub.complete();
              if (Reflect.hasMetadata(physics.PHYSICS_RIGIDBODY, this.target)) {
                const world = Injector.get(physics.World);
                world?.add(this);
              }
              return sub.complete();
            });
          } catch (e) { sub.complete(); }
        });
      }

      #addPhysics2D() {
        return new Observable<void>(sub => {
          try {
            import('@engine/physics2d').then(physics => {
              if (!physics) return sub.complete();
              if (Reflect.hasMetadata(physics.PHYSICS2D_RIGIDBODY, this.target)) {
                const world = Injector.get(physics.World2D);
                world?.add(this);
              }
              return sub.complete();
            });
          } catch (e) { sub.complete(); }
        });
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but promises do not throw errors without `await`. So your `try catch` blocks probably do nothing. You can try adding `.catch(() => sub.complete())` to see if it works.

Comment: What happens when the import isn't found? Does the catch work then?

Comment: With `forkJoin` all source Observables have to emit at least one `next` notification and then complete. It looks like you never call any `next()`

Comment: @martin That was the issue. Adding `sub.next()` right before the `try/catch` makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Seems like, you never catch errors caused by import

Clearly `@engine/physics2d` doesn't exists in the current environment, but no console log appear:

```js
try {
  import ('@engine/physics2d').then(console.log)
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', error)
}
```

### Solution

Use `await` to make promise throw an error

```js
(async() => {
  try {
    await
    import ('@engine/physics2d')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
})()
```

Use `.catch` on the promise

```js
import ('@engine/physics2d').then(console.log).catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

The last one will probably work better with your codebase

Comment: Isn't the proper solution to use `Observable.fromPromise`?

Comment: The `forkJoin` still never triggers.